# calling a part of a structure into a button click

Tags: vb.net

I'm relatively new to vb. I have made a structure and now I want to do a bubble sort on the values. I'm unsure on how to call all of the data in the single part of the structure which is also a list.
   (module)

```
      module module 1
      structure studenttype
         dim id as string
         dim name as string
      end structure 
      public studentdetails as new list(of studenttype)
```

(main code)

```
    Private Function bubbleSortbyID(ByVal namelist() As String) As String()
          Dim n As Integer = namelist.Length()
          Dim swapped As Boolean
         Do
        swapped = False
        For i As Integer = 1 To n - 2
            If namelist(i) > namelist(i + 1) Then
                Dim temp As String = namelist(i + 1)
                namelist(i + 1) = namelist(i)
                namelist(i) = temp
                swapped = True
            End If
        Next
    Loop Until swapped = False  'no swap made so order Is correct
    Return namelist
End Function
Private Sub BtnSort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles            BtnSort.Click
    Dim id As String ' it is here I do not how how to call the whole variable
    bubbleSortbyID(id)' id remains empty
    ClearAndAdd()
End Sub'''
```

Comment: Hint: `Private Function bubbleSortbyID(ByVal namelist() As List(of studenttype)) As List(of studenttype)`. Also, array indexes start at 0, not 1.

Comment: Also, is there a particular reason that you want to reinvent the sorting wheel rather than using the built-in .NET functionality (which is likely to be more efficient than anything you or I would implement at a first pass)?

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, but when I put this code in where the bubble sort function begins, an error for nameless occurs - "operator '>' is not defined for types "list(of module1.studenttype) and 'list(of Module1.studenttype"

Comment: Also, I'm trying to learn this code and see it how it will work in my own code therefore I have to use it